# Match variable and retain different numbers from each group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables -

1. the cases with a match variable;
2. the matched controls with the match variable, a randomly assigned number, and row count within each match variable group;
3. the list of match variables with the numbers of matches I want to retain within the final dataset.

So I know how to select the top 5 controls across all matched variable groups,

```
 SELECT *
 FROM [#randomID_grouped] 
 WHERE [rowcount] <= (
    SELECT MAX([sum_of_cases]) FROM [#table3]  WHERE[Match_Variable] = [Match_Variable])
 ORDER BY [#randomID_grouped].[Match_Variable]
```

But the challenge is I haven't been able to add a group by [Match_Variable] with MAX([rowcount]) to retain different numbers from each group.

I have considered using a merge into, but this doesn't work. Any ideas?

Structure of the tables ...

**Table 1 - cases**

```
ID, MatchVar

ID1, H2EF

ID2, H2EF

ID3, A3EF
```

**Table 2 - controls**

```
ID, MatchVar, RandomNumber, RowCount

ID1, H2EF, 34, 1

ID2, H2EF, 65, 2

ID3, H2EF, 75, 3
```

**Table 3 - count of match variables**

```
MatchVar, Sum_of_Cases

H2EF, 2

A3EF, 1
```

Comment: Is your question really related to both MS SQL Server and Oracle?

Comment: Opps SQL Server

Comment: Can you share the structure of the tables please?

Comment: If you're going to supply sample data, please at least align the columns (don't provide it as a delimited list). Even better though, provide is in a **consumable** format: [Forum Etiquette: How to supply data for a T-SQL: Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/)

Comment: OK thanks - will do this in future

Comment: Your query doesn't match your table definitions ( table #cases suposedly has a column rowCount that's not on your structure). Please edit the post as Larnu mentioned.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out - but in principle they were similar. Had been testing the query without the need for the third table.